# Block abusive access in web server from outside

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, xampp

What is the best way to block abusive access from outside in apache webserver ? 
If I put the IP in **/htdocs/.htaccess**, is it sufficient to deny access ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the specific IP / range to your .hataccess or if you have physical control of the machine you can always block the IP addresses via iptables / firewall.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-iptables-drop/

Comment: Not need physical access, now, I make a app that analyzes the log and adds the IP in htaccess.
I have no iptables when i use Apache on Windows :\. Any more suggestions?